# CFbuilder cfscript Unresolved Components

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I just upgraded to cfbuilder 2 and I am noticing some weird issues with the IDE. Namely that native components to ColdFusion are not recognized as valid components with in cfbuilder.

On such issue is with StoredProc(com.adobe.coldfusion.storedproc).

I should be able to do something like below and get full code complete on the variable spService. However this does not work at all, I get the warning Unresolved Component StoredProc.

Anyone know if this is a known issue?

`var spService = new StoredProc();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.  Version 2.0.0 Build: 277745

Not sure if this is the cause, but did you add CFIDE as Linked Resources?
Project Properties -> Linked Resources.

[image]